# Get the maximum Count of a range of values in an Array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I have this array. If the minimum Value is defined as 22, I want the get the maximum number of integers that are next to each other that are higher than 22.  For example, here 22 and 23 and higher or equal to 22. The loop breaks at 21. The counter is 2 integers. Then the loop goes to 22,23,23,24,22 and the counter is now 5 integers.At the end I need to get the range that delivers the maximum number of integers that is 5 in this case.
How will I write this code please? I am working for 2 days on this now.

Array:
int[] tempList = { 20, 22, 23, 21, 19, 18, 20, 22, 23, 23, 24, 22, 21 };
Min Value: 22

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] tempList = { 20, 22, 23, 21, 19, 18, 20, 22, 23, 23, 24, 22, 21 };

var g = tempList.ToArray();
int lastStartIndex = -1;
int lastEndIndex = -1;
int min = 20;
int lastSum = 0;
int i = 0;
while ( i < g.Length)
{
    if (g[i] > min)
    {
        lastStartIndex = i;

        int lastSumTemp = 0;
        int j = lastStartIndex ;
        while (j<g.Length)
        {
            if (g[j] > min)
            {
                lastSumTemp += g[j];
                j++;
                
            }
            else
            {
                if (lastSumTemp> lastSum)
                {
                    lastSum = lastSumTemp;
                    lastEndIndex = j;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        if (j==g.Length && g[j-1] > min)
        {
            if (lastSumTemp > lastSum)
            {
                lastSum = lastSumTemp;
                lastEndIndex = j-1;
            }
            break;
        }
        i = j + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        i++;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(lastStartIndex);
Console.WriteLine(lastEndIndex);
Console.WriteLine(lastSum);
Console.ReadLine();
```